# Format json string control in uwp

Tags: uwp

Is there a control in uwp that can format json string as more readable?

I mean if I have a string like

[image]

And I want a control to format it like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse the string. Insert a new line into it and `x:Bind` this method to `TextBlock.Text`:

```
    private string ParseString(string jsonString)
    {
        return jsonString.Replace(",", ",\n").Replace("{", "{\n").Replace("}", "\n}");
    }
```